# How feasible is it to start up a payment processor similar to Stripe? What would be involved?

Tags: paypal, architecture, stripe-payments, payment-processing, conceptual

I am interested in starting up a payment processor that works the same way that Stripe does. I would like to know how I would go about doing this, what would be involved, if that would even be legal (ie. does stripe have some kind of patent on their method of payment processing that would be difficult or impossible to work around) and also roughly how does stripe actually work in comparison to something like Paypal? So what is roughly the conceptual architecture of Stripe?

Comment: Too broad; off topic; ...

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer - that is what I was looking for; I did search before I asked this question but didn't find that one.

Answer (score 0):

Reading of the documentation would be involved, plus knowledge of programming / or the system you need to integrate.

Start from the manuals:

- **Stripe** [Integration Manual](https://stripe.com/docs/integrations)
- For **Paypal** the docs are here: [Development & Integration Guides](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/products/), it's similar to Stripe

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into Stellar or Ripple. They are both open source, so you can get an idea of the effort and technologies involved. You could also fork one of them, or just use them as is.

Comment: You may also want to have a look at Fineract. Also open source and currently in incubation at Apache. I'll be presenting a Fineract/Stellar connector at the Mifos tech conference next week in Amsterdam.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answers - I will look into those :)